# Provider para interceptar click em botões

Tags: angular, onclick, devexpress, angular-providers

O projeto que eu estou desenvolvendo é composto de muitos formulários com diversos botões. O que eu preciso desenvolver é uma maneira de travar cliques duplos e requisições desnecessárias para a API. Por isso desenvolvi uma diretiva que coloco em todos os botões.
`<dx-button mltClick text="Enviar"(onClick)="submit()"></dx-button>`

A diretiva basicamente impede que duplos cliques aconteçam e execute o método submit mais vezes do que deveria.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[mltClick]'
})
export class MultipleClicksDirective {
    lastClick = 0;

    constructor() {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        const currentClick = currentTime - this.lastClick;
        if (currentClick < 400) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        this.lastClick = currentTime;
    }
}
```

No entanto há um problema. Como podem ter percebido eu estou usando a DevExtreme e seus componentes então alguns botões são criados a partir do arquivo TS.

```
this.dataGrid.instance.addColumn(new ButtonsColumn().add({
     onClick: (event) => this.submit(event)
}));
```

Então percebi que o deveria colocar o código da diretiva em uma classe com um método estático dessa forma:

```
export class ButtonClickUtils {
    static clickEvent(event) {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
        const currentClick = currentTime - this.lastClick;
        if (currentClick < 400) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        this.lastClick = currentTime;
    }
}
```

E chamá-lo em todo método chamado pelos eventos de click

```
submit = (event) => {
  ButtonClickUtils.clickEvent(event);
};
```

a ideia era detectar múltiplos clicks e impedir antes de disparar o mesmo evento duas ou mais vezes.

1 problema: Diretiva funciona apenas em botões html

2 problema: Método estático não guarda o valor da variável this.lastClick;

3 problema: O projeto é composto por inúmeros botões e seria inviável dar manutenção em todos os formulários depois.

A solução que eu pensei foi criar um provider que detectasse todos os eventos de click disparados em um botão.
Mas não sei se seria a melhor solução e nem se seria viável criar um desse tipo. Se for viável como eu criaria um provider que detecta eventos de click em botões?

Comment: Ficou meio difícil de entender no fundo o que precisa, mas, basicamente pq não desabilita os botões quando clicado?

Comment: Seria uma ótima solução, mas eu teria que colocar esse código em todos os botões? Ao desativar o botão eu ia precisar ativa-lo novamente criando uma rotina duplicada em todos os formulários.

Comment: Ativa-lo e desativa-lo num curto período de forma automática funcionaria mas ia ter um ButtonClickUtils.clickEvent(); em todos os métodos?

Comment: Quando um novo programador criar um novo botão ou formulário não pode esquecer de chamar o mesmo método?

Comment: É vc que sabe aí se deveria habilitar novamente o botão, dá pra habilitar de novo. A ideia seria isso mesmo, chamar uma função e executá-la a cada clique em um botão passando sua referência, aí vc só desabilita aquele botão clicado.

Comment: daí cai no 3 problema, não posso simplesmente chamar a função em todos os botões

Comment: Não pq? Como pretende controlar status de botões sem colocar uma função para cada botão?

Comment: Cada botão tem uma rotina diferente. Eu posso acrescentar essa função de desabilitar dentro da rotina de cada um dos botões. O problema é que vai ser muitos botões e todos os dias tem botões novos sendo criados.

Answer (score -1):

Você poderia usar o debounceTime do RxJs para determinar que a sua ação seria executada depois de um certo tempo:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime